# Microsoft Cognitive-Speaker Recognition Enrollment

Tags: java, voice-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to make use of Microsoft Cognitive for Voice recognition
https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-SpeakerRecognition-Android

I have uploaded a voice sample for enrolling and got a OperationLocation object with URL in return.(Didnt see any errors or exceptions)

```
OperationLocation ops = speakerClient.enroll(audioStream, profile.identificationProfileId);
```

But when I check for status of Enrollment it always shows its "Enrolling"

```
Profile p = speakerIdClient.getProfile(UUid);
```

How much time does it take for Enrollment to be completed or is there any other issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/56406930e597ed20c8d8549c) for the enroll operation for speaker verification states that you need to submit at least 3 audios speaking the same text for the enrollment to succeed.

If you are using speaker verification, [the documentation](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/5645c3271984551c84ec6797) says that you need to submit at least 30 seconds of audio.

Comment: i am not able to wrap my head around the identification profile and verification profile.What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Speaker identification tells you who is speaking. Speaker verification tells you whether a person is who he/she says he/she is. (Think of it as two-factor authentication) @KaranGarg